# User input issue with Locale change of Site SP 2010

Tags: 2010, regional-settings, number

My site is running under SharePoint 2010. Everything is Ok except when I change the locale of my site from Regional settings from US (English) to Malay. The my web part pages where user has number inputs, stops accepting decimals. User can enter the decimal but when Saving it saves the input without decimal e.g. 1.25 becomes 125 How to get around this problem? Or how can we have all locale compliant site.

Please help.

Comment: might be worth checking the locale on the SQL server as well, I do recall a date issue whereby the SQL server has the wrong locale once

Comment: Well the UI changes the value before its sent to SQL. So whatever is displayed is saved in database.

Comment: ok so you've change the locale of both the servers regional settings as well as the site / site collection regional settings to be the same and have performed at least one iisreset on the WFE?

Comment: No I have not changed the locale of my SQL server. There is another layer in between that is web service and no change in web service locale either.

Comment: Have you find the solution for this? I am just curious...

Answer (score 3):

I tried it out on my Sharepoint environment.

- If I choose as the Regional Setting Malay (Brunei Darussalam), the accepted decimal separator is the "." (dot).
- If I choose Malay (Malaysia), the accepted decimal separator is the "," (comma).

So I think you just have to choose the other Malay regional setting. No IIS reset was needed in my tests.

I hope it helped.